# ClassyPrelude.hs:229:1: error: Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Textual.Encoding’

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Does anyone know why this application won't properly install? 
Thanks for you any help you can provide.

Brok is a web crawling program to check if files contain any broken links, I utilize it to check markdown pages. Its written in haskel and provides documentation for instalation in both cabal and stack.

```
usr@usr:~/git$ cabal install brok
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Building classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Failed to install classy-prelude-0.12.8
Build log ( /home/usr/.cabal/logs/classy-prelude-0.12.8.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-25910/classy-prelude-0.12.8'
Configuring classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Building classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Preprocessing library classy-prelude-0.12.8...
[1 of 1] Compiling ClassyPrelude    ( ClassyPrelude.hs, dist/build/ClassyPrelude.o )

ClassyPrelude.hs:203:34: error:
    Module ‘Data.Sequences’ does not export ‘intercalate’

ClassyPrelude.hs:207:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.MinLen’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ClassyPrelude.hs:208:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.ByteVector’
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Vector (needs flag -package-key vector-0.12.0.1)
      Data.Vector (from vector-0.12.3.1)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ClassyPrelude.hs:229:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Textual.Encoding’
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Text.Encoding (from text-1.2.2.2)
      Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (from text-1.2.2.2)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ClassyPrelude.hs:230:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Sequences.Lazy’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Sequences (from mono-traversable-1.0.9.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-25910/classy-prelude-0.12.8'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
brok-1.1.0 depends on classy-prelude-0.12.8 which failed to install.
classy-prelude-0.12.8 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
usr@usr:~/git$
```

I also tried `cabal install brok --reorder-goals` and `--max-backjumps 3000`

and

```
usr@usr:~/git$ cabal install classy-prelude-0.12.8
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Building classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Failed to install classy-prelude-0.12.8
Build log ( /home/usr/.cabal/logs/classy-prelude-0.12.8.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-26028/classy-prelude-0.12.8'
Configuring classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Building classy-prelude-0.12.8...
Preprocessing library classy-prelude-0.12.8...
[1 of 1] Compiling ClassyPrelude    ( ClassyPrelude.hs, dist/build/ClassyPrelude.o )

ClassyPrelude.hs:203:34: error:
    Module ‘Data.Sequences’ does not export ‘intercalate’

ClassyPrelude.hs:207:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.MinLen’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ClassyPrelude.hs:208:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.ByteVector’
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Vector (needs flag -package-key vector-0.12.0.1)
      Data.Vector (from vector-0.12.3.1)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ClassyPrelude.hs:229:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Textual.Encoding’
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Text.Encoding (from text-1.2.2.2)
      Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (from text-1.2.2.2)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ClassyPrelude.hs:230:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Sequences.Lazy’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Sequences (from mono-traversable-1.0.9.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-26028/classy-prelude-0.12.8'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
classy-prelude-0.12.8 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
usr@usr:~/git$
```

---

I even tried using stack for it:

```
usr@usr:~/git$ stack install brok
Downloading lts-18.17 build plan ...RedownloadFailed Request {
  host                 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/fpco/lts-haskell/master//lts-18.17.yaml"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 "/home/usr/.stack/build-plan/lts-18.17.yaml" (Response {responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 404, statusMessage = "Not Found"}, responseVersion = HTTP/1.1, responseHeaders = [("Connection","keep-alive"),("Content-Length","14"),("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox"),("Strict-Transport-Security","max-age=31536000"),("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff"),("X-Frame-Options","deny"),("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block"),("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=utf-8"),("X-GitHub-Request-Id","FD20:3C94:2AD54:52533:6199DAAF"),("Accept-Ranges","bytes"),("Date","Sun, 21 Nov 2021 05:35:43 GMT"),("Via","1.1 varnish"),("X-Served-By","cache-bur17534-BUR"),("X-Cache","MISS"),("X-Cache-Hits","0"),("X-Timer","S1637472943.992113,VS0,VE148"),("Vary","Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Origin"),("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"),("X-Fastly-Request-ID","a1b64bb3d228f5324b2bafca359f1c5cfa545f2a"),("Expires","Sun, 21 Nov 2021 05:40:43 GMT"),("Source-Age","0")], responseBody = (), responseCookieJar = CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose})
usr@usr:~/git$
```

**Edit**:

I also ran `cabal update` before executing these:

```
usr@usr:~/git/untitled$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Skipping download: local and remote files match.
usr@usr:~/git/untitled$
```

Comment: When was the last time you ran `cabal update`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I ran cabal update directly before executing this command.

Comment: That version of `classy-prelude` has some bad build plans according to https://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/#/package/classy-prelude. I suggest you try using a more recent version of `classy-prelude`, e.g. via `--constraint 'classy-prelude >= 1.0.0.1'`.

Comment: I've reported the problem in https://github.com/snoyberg/mono-traversable/issues/206.

Answer (score 0):

This version of `classy-prelude` was missing some dependency bounds:

- `chunked-data < 0.3`
- `mono-traversable < 1`

Both were added in revision 2: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.12.8/revisions/

If you encounter any build failures in Hackage packages in the future, please do report them on the issue tracker of the package that fails to build. If the maintainers don't respond, feel free to ask the Hackage trustees for help: https://github.com/haskell-infra/hackage-trustees